# Is Migration Assistant worth the bother?

Tags: itunes, migration

I just got a new MBP and I just tried using Migration Assistant. I didn't do this when I first turned the machine on as I (rightly) expected that it would be very lengthy.

Really all that I want to do is copy over all of my user files and iTunes library. MA doesn't seem to do this at all.

1. It wants to recreate the whole account, either overwriting the one that I created on first boot or copy the old account into a new one. I don't want to do either of those.
2. There doesn't seem to be much choice in what gets copied. Several of the items are unclear (like 'other files'), and there doesn't seem to be a way to see the details.

Will I be better off using rsync and finding a way to import my iTunes library?

Comment: You'd have been better to do it at first setup... something I discovered first time I used it. It is possible to let it create a second user, then finagle the accounts & data afterwards, but it depends how much work you've done with the new setup as to how feasible that would be. Fortunate;y did it before the new machine had done any work.

Comment: In the end I'm sticking to using rsync. I did copy my iTunes library via a network drive but that was rather slow. It doesn't help that I haven't yet bought a usb-c to ethernet adapter to speed up big transfers. I wanted to reinstall pretty much every application, so it was just the data that I wanted to copy and MA doesn't show enough information to do a good job of that.